# SQL birthday reminder, leap year in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, date, sql-studio

i'm trying to sort out a result set that sorted by upcoming birthday. This works perfectly until leap years comes into play. For example:

```
Nov 14 1991 - 200Days left
Nov 13 1988 - 200Days left
```

Here 1998 is leap year, i want sent 200days dateofbirth reminder Nov 14th in 1988 like normal year.
Dateofbirth is stored as mm-dd-yyyy. Is there a simple way to sort this problem?

```
DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, Dateofbirth) = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,(getUTCDate()+200))
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would suggest breaking your query out into two segments that can separate leap years from non-leap years. Then, you could add a column IsLeapYear so that you can check the type in your outer subquery and run the correct manipulation to your date.

I haven't tested this logic, but here's an example:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN x.IsLeapYear = 1
   THEN DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, x.Dateofbirth) = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, (getUTCDate() + 201))
  ELSE DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, x.Dateofbirth) = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, (getUTCDate() + 200))
  END AS theDate
FROM (
 SELECT DateOfBirth
  ,1 AS IsLeapYear
 FROM yourTable
 WHERE (
   YEAR(DateOfBirth) % 4 = 0
   AND YEAR(DateOfBirth) % 100 != 0
   )
  OR (YEAR(DateOfBirth) % 400 = 0)
 
 UNION
 
 SELECT DateOfBirth
  ,0 AS IsLeapYear
 WHERE (
   YEAR(DateOfBirth) % 4 != 0
   OR YEAR(DateOfBirth) % 100 = 0
   )
  AND (YEAR(DateOfBirth) % 400 != 0)
 ) AS x
```